# Modify a single observation in a SAS data set

Tags: sas, datastep

Suppose I have the following data set:

```
data people;
    input name $ age;
    datalines;
Timothy 25
Mark 30
Matt 29
;
run;
```

How can I change the age of a particular person? Basically, I want to know how to specify a `name` and tell SAS to change that person's (observation's) `age` value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple case:

```
data want;
set people;
if name='Mark' then age=31;
run;
```

You can change it in the same dataset a number of ways:

```
proc sql;
  update want 
    set age=31 
    where name='Mark';
quit;


data people;
set people;
if name='Mark' then age=31;
run;


data people;
modify people;
if name='Mark' then age=31;
run;
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I especially appreciate seeing multiple solutions.